# pam_tally total tries, instead of user-specific?

Tags: pam

Is there a way to log the total number of failed attempts, rather than user-specific ones?

At the moment the counter only logs valid users.

If the attacker is trying unknown logins, I want these to be registered too.

Answer (score 2):

Failed attempts to login is unknown users will be logged in `/var/log/secure`.

You won't see them with `pam_tally` because that `pam_tally.so` module will not be reached in your PAM stack when someone attempts to log in with a non-existent user.